# Using IsLike in NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I know that it gives some solutions for this error already but I dont find out why I got this error. When I load the List without filtered it works.

```
if (searchString != "") {
            query = _pagedDataQueryProcessor.GetDefaultQuery<Data.Entities.Password>()
                .Where(
                Restrictions.Disjunction()
                    .Add(Restrictions.On<Data.Entities.Password>(x => x.Name).IsLike(searchString))
                    .Add(Restrictions.On<Data.Entities.Password>(x => x.Description).IsLike(searchString))
                    .Add(Restrictions.On<Data.Entities.Password>(x => x.PasswordText).IsLike(searchString))
   );
}
```

I found out what the problem was

**Solution:**

```
if (searchString != "") {
            query = _pagedDataQueryProcessor.GetDefaultQuery<Data.Entities.Password>()
                .Where(
                Restrictions.Disjunction()
                    .Add(Restrictions.On<Data.Entities.Password>(x => x.Name).IsLike("%" + searchString + "%"))
                    .Add(Restrictions.On<Data.Entities.Password>(x => x.Description).IsLike("%" + searchString + "%"))
                    .Add(Restrictions.On<Data.Entities.Password>(x => x.PasswordText).IsLike("%" + searchString + "%"))
);
```

What did i changed? i didn't had the "%".

Here I want to filter a list but when I wrote something in the input i always got a empty list.

searchstring is the filtered word

data.entities.password is the list on the db

Can someone help me I dont know what i make wrong.

Comment: Whatever the "_pagedDataQueryProcessor" is.

Comment: There is another solution by passing a second argument to IsLike. See my answer.

Comment: I adapted the title, I hope that's Ok for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add wildcards or add a second argument to `IsLike`.

```
...IsLike("%" + searchString + "%"))
```

You can put the wildcard anywhere in the string, e.g. only at the beginning or only at the end.

Or

```
...IsLike(searchString, MatchMode.Anywhere)
```

You can also use `MatchMode.Start` or `MatchMode.End`.